# Error 1105 - why is SQL saying PRIMARY file group is full, when it's not?

Tags: sql-server

I'm relatively new to SQL Server, but I am now getting an error which I understand in theory, but when looking at the possible causes no longer makes any sense.

I have a hosted, virtual Windows installation with a host provider, with SQL Server (not Express) 18.4. I did recently have to upgrade the amount of HD space available to the server via the host website, but it is an SSD and the extra space is showing as available to C drive, which is where the file are being stored:

[image]

[image]
I am at a loss therefore to work out how to resolve the issue, but as I said at the top...I'm not an expert in SQL.

Any advice offered would be appreciated. Cheers.

PS - I've added the Filegroup page here...

Result of `SELECT @@VERSION` is

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64) Aug 22 2017
>   17:04:49 Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation Express Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 17763: )
>   (Hypervisor)

[image]

Comment: There is no SQL Server 18.4. The latest edition of SQL Server is SQL Server 2019 which is current at version 15.0.4023.6 (if you have the latest CU installed). As for the error, it's telling you the filegroup is full, not the Hard Disk. Actually post the **full** error in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant SSMS. SQL Server: 15.0.18206.0. The full error is Msg 1105, Level 17, State 2, Line 5
Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.CareNotes' in database 'PCSUtility' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

Comment: All the versions that you give us are **SSMS** versions (so the Client tools), not SQL Server versions (i.e. the Server software). You need to understand the difference, and then post the ***actual*** SQL Server versions (i.e. the Server software).

Comment: *"SQL Server: 15.0.18206.0"* That's definately not your version either. As I said *"The latest edition of SQL Server is SQL Server 2019 which is **current at version 15.0.4023.6** (if you have the latest CU installed)."* SQL server Version  15.0.18206.0 would be something like SQL Server 2019 CU 29 (and I doubt it'll ever get that high.)

Comment: I suggest you run `SELECT @@VERSION` inside SSMS and post the result

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)......I've just seen the word EXPRESS for the first time. Does this mean what I think it means? I thought because it was already over 10gb that it must've been just a coincidence...

Comment: Dude it is express edition. @DanGuzman's answer is correct. I'll edit it into your question.

Comment: F*** sake. I got the server thinking it was the full version, not just another Express edition. OK guys, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Express Edition databases are limited to 10GB according to the [scale limits in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server). Data files will not grow beyond 10GB so you'll get the filegroup full error once the database has reached the limit and no unused space is available within the file(s).

Comment: Thank you, though I am not using Express edition. I made sure of that before posting.

Comment: @Ant, double-check with `SELECT @@VERSION`.